# How to use real Bitmap object in Robolectric unit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-bitmap, robolectric

I'd like to use [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap) (resource from res folder and from uri) in my [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) unit tests, but the given object is always empty. I know that Robolectric uses [ShadowBitmap](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowBitmap.html), but I'm curious if it's possible (and how) to use real Bitmaps in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Robolectric improved massive fidelity for `Bitmap` and `BitmapFactory` from [robolectric-4.6](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-4.6), maybe you can try it. The [robolectric-4.6.1](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-4.6.1) is more recommended, because it has better compatibility for target SDK 29 and 28.